# Auto Scroll CSS Button

Tags: html, css

How do I make the the page auto scroll to the bottom of the dropdown button on hover? I want the bottom of the page to meet the bottom of the button and I don't want it to scroll really fast. I've tried a bit of javascript but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/5gq9E/

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='has-sub last'  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>Choose a 
model</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC Aria</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC Rhyme</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC Surround</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC Sensation</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC Thunderbolt</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC One S</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC One X</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC Evo 4G</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC Inspire 4G</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC MyTouch 4G</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC Evo 4G LTE</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC Evo Shift 4G</span></a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC Evo Droid Incredible 2</span>  
</a></li>
     <li  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC Windows Phone 8X</span></a>  
</li>
     <li class='last'  id="iefix"><a rel=nofollow href='#'><span>HTC One</span></a>
</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're after. Perhaps you could post a screen mock-up of what you want it to look like?

Comment: I don't think that could be achieved, maybe with advanced custom coded JS. You can try using **:target**, but that will have to be on-click. The best solution is, instead of scrolling to the bottom, just add another row to your navigation.

Comment: First, get rid of all the identical ids in your source. Then, would `document.getElementById('iefix').scrollIntoView(false)` work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#choose').live('hover',function() {
  var postion =  $("#categories li:last-child").offset();
  var top1 =  postion.top;
  var left1 = postion.left;

 window.scrollTo(top1, left1);
```

});

You can try with this one. #choose for "choose a model" - span and #categories for ul containing all li.

Comment: The OP never mentioned using jQuery, and you should never assume they are if it's not explicitly said so